# EASA part 66 licence conversion to the Japanese version?

Tags: aircraft-maintenance, easa, japan

I am looking at a job proposal in Japan. I need to transfer my EASA Part 66 engineers license to the Japanese version.

Can anybody offer any advice on how I would achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

You'll probably need a letter from your part 66 licence holder's authority.
I know people who get equivalent between French and Australian.
The best approach is to contact the Japan's competent authority (JCAB-MLIT) for the application details.
Regards